# ATG - Endeca Partial indexing record count

Tags: search, indexing, atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

The partial indexing process creates more records than the Baseline updates.

During Baseline updates, `ProductCatalogOutputConfig` component, produces record count of 400.000

But during partial updates, even if one product is modified, the record count is more than the record count that was generated during Baseline.

The tables of `IncrementalItemQueueRepository` was examined and the records in `srch_update_queue` table but no break thoughs.

How to debug the issue here and also is there a way to calculate the probable record count.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. On the `/atg/search/repository/IncrementalItemQueueRepository` set the `debugLevel` to 10 and flush the cache.
2. Query the table `srch_update_queue` in the core schema and get a count
3. Run partial update and make sure that this table has cleared down.
4. Make a simple change and again query the above table check the your items are in the queue
5. Run partial update again

You might need to truncate the `srch_update_queue` especially if you have not been using this in the past and there are thousands of old updates in the queue.

To force the incremental entries to be automatically deleted when running a baseline update, set the `forceDeleteGenerations=true` on the component `/atg/commerce/search/ProductCatalogOutputConfig/`. There might be other output configs that you need to set this on depending on your configuration.

Comment: Thanks.. Instead of partial, if baseline is executed manually, should the data be removed manually from the tables to avoid this data be indexed once again through partial indexing?

Comment: If you are only using baseline indexes then I would disable the incrementals. However if you are using it I would recommend deleting just prior to running the baseling index.